# Incorrect SCNNode position values after CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: swift, arkit

I launched a CAKeyframeAnimation on a SCNNode added to a sprite kit scene (ARKit project).
The node moves perfectly and fires animation start/stop events correctly. However the position values of the node remains the same.

Here is the node adding, I checked it is added once and only once :

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "fish_idle_1_\(GameManager.selectedFishSkin+1)")
fishNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
fishNode.name = "fish"
fishNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(fishNode)
```

The animation launch, works correctly :

```
    let pendulumSwings = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "translation")

    pendulumSwings.duration = time
    pendulumSwings.repeatCount = 1
    pendulumSwings.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    pendulumSwings.values = computedVectors
    pendulumSwings.delegate = self

    fishNode.removeAllAnimations()
    fishNode.addAnimation(pendulumSwings, forKey: nil)
```

The delegate code :

```
extension Game: CAAnimationDelegate {
func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
    guard let viewController = viewController else { return }
    guard let first = viewController.anchors.first else { return }
    guard let last = viewController.anchors.last else { return }
    print("START \(fishNode.position)")
    print("SCENE START \(viewController.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "fish", recursively: false)!.position)")
}

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    guard let viewController = viewController else { return }
    guard let first = viewController.anchors.first else { return }
    guard let last = viewController.anchors.last else { return }
    print("END \(fishNode.position)")
    print("SCENE END \(viewController.sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "fish", recursively: false)!.position)")
}
}
```

Both 4 print statements display the same values (values depending on use case) :

START SCNVector3(x: 0.386469185, y: -0.640618205, z: 0.609007716)

I can't get any feedback on how the node position is moved on the scene, so I cannot perform any calculation based on node's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your node's `.presentation` property. That is where the node's position is while an animation is acting on the node.

For you, print `fishNode.presentation.position` instead of `fishNode.position`

From Apple doc:

> The presentation node’s properties provide a close approximation to
>   the version of the node that is currently displayed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408030-presentation

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know about this copy system.

Comment: It is a huge "gotcha" in Scenekit. I lost a lot of time because of this as well.